# Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 removes custom colors for classes

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, ide, customization

I've been using custom editor colors for Visual Studio for a few years now, through several versions. I just updated 2013 to Update 4, and now all my colors got screwed up. I reset to the default dark theme to go from there, and I noticed you can no longer change the color of classes and structs, or any identifier for that matter (I use C#). Instead they use the default color. What is happening?

EDIT: This seems to have occurred for VS2012 as well...

Comment: I don't know of any change in Update 4 that would have caused this. Can you share more details around how you're trying to change the colors and what actually happens?

Comment: @gusp There are no options available in Options -> Fonts and Colors to change "User Type" formatting, or formatting for other types of identifiers (such as interfaces, fields, local variables, etc). For some reason formatting for enums still works fine. This might be due to the fact that there was an update to VS, rather than Update 4 itself.

Comment: Strangely enough, importing my settings from my VS2013 Express install (This problem was occuring with Professional) completely eliminated this problem. How odd. A full answer will be put below.

Comment: Happy to hear you were able to figure it out. I'll share your findings with the team; there's likely something we need to fix around this.

Comment: @GusP SQL Queries are barely readable with the default dark colorscheme. Maybe this is related to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of my problem: **Color Theme Editor Extension**

It turns out that when the problem occurred I had the color theme editor installed on VS2013 Pro and VS2012 Pro. Even after I disabled it in VS2013, the problem remained in VS2013 Pro and VS2012 Pro and Express for Windows Desktop, so I dismissed that as the cause at first.

What was odd is that it did not occur in VS2013 Express for Windows Desktop. Resetting Visual Studio (any problematic version) to default settings did *not* fix the problem, it only made it less noticeable. I still had custom fonts and colors from my VS2013 Express installation, so I exported them then imported them into VS2013 Pro.

For anyone else who seems to be getting this issue because of this extension, try installing 2013 Express and re-creating your custom fonts and colors there, and importing the settings back into Premium/Professional/Ultimate. I am not sure if it will work for everyone, but doing that with my previous install worked for me.